# NDSolve issue, potential singularity or stiff system

Tags: differential-equations, numerics, parameters

I have the following parameters, equations, and NDSolve solution set up as such:

```
ROCP = 1;
RICP = 0;
ROCS1 = 0.4;
RICS1 = 0.99;
L = 5 10^-2;
n = 1.556;
c = 3 10^8;
lR = 0.03;
R1 = 0.99;

gP = 2*10^-10;
gS1 = 2*10^-10;
sigmaSP = 10^-18;

toffset = 5 10^-9;
twidth = 10 10^-9;
Energy = 0.00013;
rad = 0.00015;
PumpInt = ((Energy)/(twidth))/(Pi rad^2);
PumpPeak = Exp[0.5 ((-toffset)/(twidth))^2] PumpInt;

lc = n lR;
alphaP = L/(2 lc);
alphaS1 = (L - Log[R1])/(2 lc);

tmax = 20 10^-9;

ppR = 100;


eqn1 = -D[IPF[z, t], z] - (n/c) D[IPF[z, t], t] - 
  gP*IPF[z, t]*(IS1F[z, t] + IS1B[z, t]) - alphaP IPF[z, t]
eqn2 = 
 D[IPB[z, t], z] - (n/c) D[IPB[z, t], t] - 
  gP IPB[z, t] (IS1F[z, t] + IS1B[z, t]) - alphaP IPB[z, t]
eqn3 = -D[IS1F[z, t], z] - (n/c) D[IS1F[z, t], t] + 
  gS1 IS1F[z, t] (IPF[z, t] + IPB[z, t]) - alphaS1 IS1F[z, t] + 
  sigmaSP (IPF[z, t] + IPB[z, t])
eqn4 = 
 D[IS1B[z, t], z] - (n/c) D[IS1B[z, t], t] + 
  gS1 IS1B[z, t] (IPF[z, t] + IPB[z, t]) - alphaS1 IS1B[z, t] + 
  sigmaSP (IPF[z, t] + IPB[z, t])


solIntEqn = NDSolve[{
    eqn1 == 0, eqn2 == 0, eqn3 == 0, 
    eqn4 == 0,
    IPF[0, t] == PumpPeak*Exp[-0.5 ((t - toffset)/twidth)^2], 
    IPB[lR, t] == IPF[lR, t] ROCP, IS1F[0, t] == IS1B[0, t] RICS1, 
    IS1B[lR, t] == IS1F[lR, t] ROCS1,
    IPB[z, 0] == PumpPeak*Exp[-0.5 ((-toffset)/twidth)^2], 
    IPF[z, 0] == PumpPeak*Exp[-0.5 ((-toffset)/twidth)^2], 
    IS1F[z, 0] ==  0, IS1B[z, 0] ==  0},
   {IPF, IPB, IS1F, IS1B}, {z, 0, lR}, {t, 0, tmax}, 
   MaxSteps -> Infinity,
   PrecisionGoal -> 1,
   AccuracyGoal -> 50, 
   Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
     "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
       "MinPoints" -> ppR,
       "MaxPoints" -> ppR, "DifferenceOrder" -> 2},
     Method -> {"Adams", "MaxDifferenceOrder" -> 1}}];
```

However, whenever I run NDSolve I encounter the error:

**NDSolve::ndsz: At t == 1.776028263551613`*^-9, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected.**

How can I resolve this issue?

Potentially helpful info: when gS1 = 0, there is no problem running the code.

Cheers!

Edit: Parameters that have been altered to ns units

```
c = 3 10^-1;
gP = 2*10^-1;
gS1 = 2*10^-1;
toffset = 5;
twidth = 10;
tmax = 20;
```

where c has units (m/ns), gP and gS1 (m*ns/J), and t (ns)

Further update:
By using the original parameters posted and by changing sigmaSP to 10^-200, I obtain the correct solutions for IPF[z,t] and IPB[z,t], however, not for IS1F[z,t] and IS1B[z,t]

Further edit: Because of the excellent advice I had received, I decided to play with the units which has resolved my original problem, however I am not quite getting the correct graph for IS1B[z,t]. Here are the updated parameters and the code for my graph:

```
 ROCP = 1;
RICP = 0;
ROCS1 = 0.4;
RICS1 = 0.99;
L = 5 10^-2;
n = 1.556;
c = 30;
lR = 3;
R1 = 0.99;

gP = 20 10^9;
gS1 = 20 10^9;
sigmaSP = 1.5 10^-20;

toffset = 5 ;
twidth = 10 ;
Energy = 0.00013*10^-9;
rad = 0.015;
PumpInt = ((Energy)/(twidth))/(Pi rad^2) 10^-9;
PumpPeak = Exp[0.5 ((-toffset)/(twidth))^2] PumpInt;

lc = n lR;
alphaP = L/(2 lc);
alphaS1 = (L - Log[R1])/(2 lc);

tmax = 20 ;



firStoIntBt = 
 Manipulate[
  Plot[{IS1B[z, t] /. solIntEqn}, {z, 0, lR}, PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotLegends -> {IS1B}, 
   AxesLabel -> {"z (cm)", 
     "Intensity (GW \!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(cm\), \(-2\)]\))"}, 
   PlotLabel -> "First Stokes Intensity vs z as t changes"], {t, 0, 
   tmax}]
```

Units: ROCP,RICP,ROCS1,RICS1,L,n,R1 are unitless, c (cm/ns),lR (cm), gP and gS1 (cm*ns/GJ), sigmaSP (cm^-1), t (ns), rad (cm), Energy (GJ), PumpInt and PumpPeak (GJ/(ns*cm^2)), lc (cm), alphaP and alphaS1 (cm^-1).

Comment: The large constants probably are causing numerical problems but perhaps can be reduced in size by rescaling independent and dependent variables.  For instance, rescaling `t` by `3 10^8` will make the coefficients of the temporal and spatial derivatives comparable.

Comment: Hi, just a quick update, I took your advice and changed from units of seconds to nanoseconds but I'm now left with a similar error: At t == 1.8487013333202573`, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected. I will update my post to include the new values.

Comment: I found that by making sigmaSP very small I avoid the error but now I get oscillations in by NDSolve graphs.

Comment: After taking your advice, I decided to scale other units which has fixed my original problem. Thank you very much. I'm not quite sure about the graph I'm obtaining for IS1B[z,t], and am wondering if this is just a failure on the numerical methods I'm using and if it can be fixed? Cheers for the help!

Comment: It is not possible to comment on the graph without seeing the graph itself and all the code that produced it.